# batchgetbyfilter googlesheetsApi v4 in node

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Data is inserted in google excel sheet. When next time data is inserted with extra column  then the sheet should be take the existing column and should add another column in the existing row. If data is not existing then should add a new row.

Is there any way to satisfy my requirement using google sheets API v4. I am working on Node. Here I am attaching my code sample to get an idea.

[image]

Comment: Please, post what you have trying.

Comment: No code sampe provided - please edit your question

Comment: find https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGetByDataFilter

but I'm not sure where to add findData and where to add replacementData

Comment: You need to read first and put that column number in a temp variable. Then start insertion onward to that column number

Comment: how to read only particular row which I want @NaveedRamzan

Comment: @BHANUPRAKASH, well you need to read all rows one by one.